# jQuery bug in safari 8.0.4 'invalid character '\u0215'

Tags: jquery, safari

The video of bug attached bellow.

The error appears every time I want to sign up or sign in on a website. I see the terrible error at my console in the browser 'Syntax error invalid character '\u0215'. I look through my code so many times and I did not found any error. I use magnific popup library to show the popup for sign-in and sign up. 
On other browsers, it works fine this error appears only on safari.

I found some discussion here https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/556, but I can't understand what I need to do.

I made a quick video here is the link http://quick.as/gv2au9mj6.
I also can't click on регистриция link and some other links which I did not show on video.